# How to set alert-rule for a particular namespace

Tags: prometheus, promql

How can we set an alert for a particular namespace regarding instances up or down for it?

I'm new to this so this might sound very basic..

```yaml
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."
```

I'm using this but it gives alert for all instances and pods down so how to set for a namespace.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question, so it is easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Alert rule in Prometheus creates an alert if `expr` returns any time series.

In your case query `up == 0` will return result whenever any instance is down (since you have `for` clause in your rule, whenever it is down for 5 minutes).

To limit this rule to single namespace you probably can use something like `up{namespace="my_namespace_1"} == 0` (but it may depend on exporters being used). Check out if metric `up` for desired target have label `namespace` (you can do it in web UI of Prometheus).

More generally you can check your alert expressions there too. Switch to graph mode, set appropriate time range and enter desired query, and you'll see when expressions return something.

Also, I recommend to familiarize yourself with Prometheus' documentation: it is rather clearly explains most points of Prometheus usage and worth investing your time. Specifically for this case: [basics of querying](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) and [alerting rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to alert for a particular namespace, just APPEND a `namespace` label to your `expr`, which would be like this `expr: up{namespace="your-ns"}` .

I recommend an easy way to set alert rule in WebUI using [Nightingale project](https://github.com/ccfos/nightingale). A typical screenshot may looks like as bellow => https://n9e.github.io/images/intro/rule-config.png